# Calling more than one Mapper with different InputFormatClass in MapReduce

Tags: java, xml, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I want to write a code with three `Mapper` of which two will process `".csv"` file other is `".xml"`. I have written `XmlInputFormat` for `.xml` format from [here](http://thinkbigdataanalytics.com/xmlinputformat-hadoop/)

Now I want to know what should I have to input

```
job.setInputFormatClass(...);
```

And also which should I add to provide path of files.

```
 TextInputFormat.addInputPath(...)
 TextOutputFormat.setInputPath(...)
```

OR

```
TextInputFormat.addInputPath(...)
TextOutputFormat.setInputPath(...)
```

Comment: I have added on how to use `MultipleInputs` to achieve this. Kindy check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think towards writing two mapper, one processing `.csv` file and other `.xml`. However, both the mapper should produce `key-value` of `same type`, for a single reducer to process it.

Here goes an example to use the `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.MultipleInputs` for the same:

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(jobConf, 
                     new Path(csvFilePath),       
                     SequenceFileInputFormat.class, 
                     CSVProcessingMapper.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(jobConf, 
                     new Path(xmlFilePath), 
                     XmlInputFormat.class, 
                     XMLProcessingMapper.class);
```

Here `CSVProcessingMapper.class` and `XmlInputFormat.class` are the `CSV` and `XML` processing mapper. You may as many mapper for different input types.
Similarly `SequenceFileInputFormat.class` and `XmlInputFormat.class` classes are the corresponding input format classes.